# How to eliminate unwanted padding you have no control over?

Tags: css

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.background{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image:url('http://tombricker.smugmug.com/Travel/San-Francisco-California/i-jk2Z7D7/0/L/san-francisco-golden-gate-bridge-morning-sun-bricker-L.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.location{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  color:white;
  font-size:100px;
  
  padding:0;
  padding-top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">

<div class='background'>
  <div class='location'>San Francisco</div>
</div>
```

I tried padding-top:-23 px; to try to suck the words up but it won't move. Only margin-top does the job. I try to eliminate the space to the left and above "San".If you make background:grey; on .location you will see that the blank space is padding not margin.

Comment: **For future readers:** Also make sure it's not due to positioning. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no padding on the element. You can inspect the Code Snippet with Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox and hover the element. You will see, that the element has no padding aswell as no margin.
The problem here, is the font you use. Try a smaller line height with: `line-height: ;`.

Comment: Is there a font with no padding and margin? I don't which Google Font has no space around it.

Comment: Most of Google Fonts should have no useless padding around it. I like to use [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the font. Play with `line-height`. This might help.

Never use negative paddings or margins. If you need to do this. You do it wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all... padding:-10px; this will not work. The solution is you can play with line height for top and bottom space, and text-indent for left space as i did in your code. please check demo:

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
.background {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('http://tombricker.smugmug.com/Travel/San-Francisco-California/i-jk2Z7D7/0/L/san-francisco-golden-gate-bridge-morning-sun-bricker-L.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.location {
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 color: white;
 font-size: 100px;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 62px;
 text-indent: -6px;
 text-align: left;
 padding-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
<div class='background'>
  <div class='location'>San Francisco</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a padding. If you make the header background grey, you will see that. The space is inside the grey box.

Comment: I just used some negative margin. https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/ayoaLv?editors=1100